# spark scala cannot resolve column with using agg

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code:

```
def proccess(spark: SparkSession, df : DataFrame): DataFrame= {
  val mydf = df.withColumn("next_intent_temp", when (col("next_intent")=== "val", 1).otherwise(0)
  
  val mynewdf = mydf.groupBy(col("a"), col("b"), col("c")
                .agg(sum(col("next_intent_temp")).as("next_intent"))
                .select(col("market"), struct(col("next_intent"),...).alias("data")
    )
  mynewdf 

}
```

Running it gives:

```
cannot resolve 'next_intent_temp' given input columns [...]; Aggregate [sum('next_intent_temp')...
```

I don't really understand this error because when I do `mydf.show()` I do see the column next_intent_temp with the correct values. so why the sum fails with this error?

Noting: I simplified the code for the question but preserved the structure that I really have.

Comment: Updated answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `.as("next_intent")`. Use that column name.

I think you have some syntax and missing ) aspects.

This is a simpler example, but if you follow it, you should be ok.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq( (1,7,"ST"), (1,8,"XX"), (1,9,"RW"), (3,10,"ST"), (3,11,"AA"), (3,12,"RW"), (2,3,"ST"), (2,4,"TT"))).toDF("i", "c", "t")
val df2 = df.withColumn("next_intent_temp", lit(1))

val df3 = df2.groupBy(col("i"), col("c"), col("t"))
             .agg(sum(col("next_intent_temp")).as("next_intent"))
             .select(col("i"), struct(col("next_intent")).alias("data"))
                        
df3.show(false)
```

Comment: use where? I want to sum the values in next_intent_temp and call the summed column next_intent so the sum function needs to be on next_intent_temp

Comment: can you also help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74381452/how-to-extract-value-from-json-column-in-spark-scala