# How to extract value from json column in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following code:

```
class MyTest extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers {

   ....

  it should "calculate" in {

    val testDf= Seq(
      testDf(1, "customer1", "Hi"),
      testDf(1, "customer2", "Hi")
    ).toDS().toDF()


    val out = MyClass.procOut(spark, testDf)
    out.count() should be(1)
    out.where(col("customer_id")==="customer1").first().getString(output.first().fieldIndex("json_col")) should be(?) // Here I have problem!

  }

}
```

My issue:
`out` is dataframe the:

```
out.where(col("customer_id")==="customer1").first().getString(output.first().fieldIndex("json_col"))
```

extract the json column so it has:

```
{
  "statistics": {
    "Group2": {
      "buy": 1
    }
  }
}
```

my goal is to get the value of `buy` e.g to assert that the value in the json is 1.

so I want to do something like:

```
out.where(col("customer_id")==="customer1").first().getString(output.first().fieldIndex("json_col")["statistics"]["Group2"]["buy"]) should be (1)
```

obviously this is not the right syntax but I can't find what is the right syntax to extract specific value from json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `json_tuple` - Extract the Data from JSON and create them as a new columns.

```scala
val jsonString="""{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PARC PARQUE","State":"PR"}"""
val data = Seq((1, jsonString))
import spark.implicits._
val df=data.toDF("id","value")
```

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{json_tuple}
df.select(col("id"),json_tuple(col("value"),"Zipcode","ZipCodeType","City"))
  .toDF("id","Zipcode","ZipCodeType","City")
  .show(false)
```

- `get_json_object` – Extracts JSON element from a JSON string based on json path specified.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{get_json_object}
df.select(col("id"),get_json_object(col("value"),"$.ZipCodeType").as("ZipCodeType"))
  .show(false)
```